# ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Errors with Custom Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-2-validation, custom-exceptions

**I have a custom exception class:**

```
public class MyException: Exception
{
   public MyException(MyExceptionEnum myError) : base(myError.ToDescription()) { }
   public MyException(MyExceptionEnum myError, Exception innerException) : base(myError.ToDescription(), innerException) { }
}
```

`.ToDescription` is a extension method on `MyExceptionEnum` to provide enum-to-string mapping for the exception error details.

**Here's how i throw it:**

```
if (someCondition)
   throw new MyException(MyExceptionEnum.SomeError);
```

So i use my first ctor, which creates a new Exception with a given message.

**Now onto the Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateFoo(Foo model)
{
   try
   {
      _fooService.UpdateModel(model);
      _unitOfWork.Commit();
   }
   catch(MyException myException)
   {
      ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ModelErrors", myException);
   }

   return View("Index", model);
}
```

**And finally a snippet from the View:**

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessage("ModelErrors") %>
```

Doesn't work (exception is thrown when i debug, error is added to model state, but nothing shown on page).

But if i change to the following line:

```
ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ModelErrors", myException.Message);
```

It works.

`AddModelError` has two overloads:

1. string, Exception (doesn't work for me)
2. string, string (works)

What is the use of the first overload then? My Exception does have an inner exception message, so i would have thought the HTML Extension would render that?

How do we handle custom exceptions with the ModelState then? Is using the second overload correct?

Comment: +1 on the q; I noticed this happen once with a CLR exception; I ended up changing it to use `.Message` and told myself I'd look into it later. :P

Comment: :) Yes, i am tempted to go "oh, looks like .Message works, that's good enough". But being a good little developer boy i want to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't matter whether it's a custom exception or pre-defined one. It just doesn't work.
If you have a chance to look at the MVC source code for **ModelError** class, you can see that it has an public string property **ErrorMessage** which is used to display the error when validation happens (in **ValidationExtensions** class).

In the overload constructor of **ModelError(Exception exception)**, though, it just sets the **ErrorMessage** property as empty string, rather than **exception.Message**. That's why you see nothing.

Comment: So are you saying this is a bug with MVC?

Comment: +1 for clarifying that it doesn't seem to matter whether it's CLR/custom exception, and for checking the source!