# MVC4 Database Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to perform a database action on login click.
So i am using stored procedure for getting the data, but here i am facing some issues regarding model exception.

```
public ActionResult Login(UserInfo model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<UserInfo> loginDetails = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<UserInfo>
                    ("exec spGetloginUserInfo @username,@password", new SqlParameter("@username", model.username), new SqlParameter("@password", model.password)).ToList();
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

My Model

```
  public class UserInfo
    {
        public string usertype { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastmodifieddate { get; set; }
        public string modifiedby { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

The exception thrown is

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Please let me know where i am doing wrong and also whether my approach is right?
And also is there any other way for database interaction other that stored procedure approach.

Comment: are you sure all not nullable properties are passed before calling your Login action, i.e. lastmodifieddate ?
regarding your approach, if I were u, I would write my logic in linq instead of SP to avoid scattering my business logic in more than one tier

Comment: ya i am sure all are not nullable. how do i use linq in this case. can you please throw more light on this.

Comment: Its asking me to define a key for EntityType 'UserInfo'. I dont know what kind of key it is looking for

Comment: I didn't mean make all properties not nullable, because this depends on your business. I mean if a value is not nullable you should pass it a value to make the ModelStat.IsValid equal true. For using Linq, I need to know the nature of data you want to retrieve to be able to help. but I recommend you read some tutorial or search from online linq sample codes

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.AddModelError throws an error but your client/javascript/views did not catch that error.

Here is a link on how to implement similar error handling in views.

[ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Errors with Custom Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029330/asp-net-mvc-2-model-errors-with-custom-exceptions)

Also, make sure the your model UserInfo has valid data for each properties

```
Login(UserInfo model, string returnUrl) <<-- the model of type UserInfo
```

Comment: Its asking me to define a key for EntityType 'UserInfo'. I dont know what kind of key it is looking for

Comment: You should put a @Model modelname in your views